# React- Router not show component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have already read all related entries. However, my problem still exists.
I have the following App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import About_Screen from './screen/About_Screen.js';

class App extends Component {

 constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.state = {};
 }

render(){
 return(

  <div className="app">     
    <main role="main">
    <Jumbotron fluid>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
       <NavLink to="/About_Screen">About</NavLink>
        <Panel collapsible expanded={this.state.open}>
         wes anderson
        </Panel>
   </Jumbotron>
<Grid>
<Row>
<Col xs={6} md={2}>
  <Thumbnail src={require("./watch.png")}>
    <h5>Thumbnail label</h5>
      <Button onClick={ ()=> this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })}>
        ?
      </Button>
      <Panel collapsible expanded={this.state.open}>
      Smart
      </Panel>
      <p>
       <Checkbox inline></Checkbox>
      </p>
   </Thumbnail>
 </Col>
 ....
   )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
 <App>  
  <Route exact path="/" component={About_Screen}></Route>
  <Route path="/About_Screen" component ={About_Screen}> </Route>
 </App>    
</BrowserRouter>, 
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I try to link via NavLink within the jumbotron to my About_Screen.js. This is also displayed in the URL (http: // localhost: 8080 / About_Screen). Unfortunately the routing does not work.
Here's About_Screen.js:

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

```
 class About_Screen extends React.Component{

  render (){
   return(
    <div>  
     <h1>SCREEN 1 DATA</h1>
    </div>  
   );
  }
 }
 export default About_Screen;
```

Where is my mistake? Do I link the routing wrong?
My data structure looks as follows:

- App

  - src

    - App.js
    - index.html

      - screen
      - About_Screen.js

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you have `{ this.props.children }`, anywhere in your `App` component render method?

Comment: No. Where should I add this?

Comment: Wherever  you want to render your `About_Screen`

Comment: When I enter About_Screen I want to show (more or less) the same page. So everythink should be renderd.

Comment: Where do you want your `SCREEN 1 DATA` to show?

Comment: This is just a "placeholder" that I can see the changes between the start page and the renderd About_Screen page

Comment: Where do you want to see the changes? Your App class is actually rendering and somewhere inside you ( probably ) want to render your routed component ( `SCREEN 1 DATA` ), that's the place that you need to put your `{ this.props.children }` in it.

Comment: {import React, {Component} from 'react';
              import {Link} from 'react-router';

              class About_Screen extends React.Component{

               render (){
                 return(
                  <div>  
                    <h1>SCREEN 1 DATA</h1>
                      { this.props.children }
                    </div>  
                  );
                 }
               }
             export default About_Screen;}

Comment: It should be in your `App` component as my first comment stated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained above, you do not print anything in your `App` class. You need to insert `{this.props.children}` in it. For example:

```
class App extends Component {

 constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.state = {};
}

render(){
 return(

  <div className="app">     
    <main role="main">
    <Jumbotron fluid>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
       <NavLink to="/About_Screen">About</NavLink>
        <Panel collapsible expanded={this.state.open}>
         // this is the code to print About_Screen
         {this.props.children}
        </Panel>
   </Jumbotron>
<Grid>
<Row>
<Col xs={6} md={2}>
  <Thumbnail src={require("./watch.png")}>
    <h5>Thumbnail label</h5>
      <Button onClick={ ()=> this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })}>
        ?
      </Button>
      <Panel collapsible expanded={this.state.open}>
      Smart
      </Panel>
      <p>
       <Checkbox inline></Checkbox>
      </p>
   </Thumbnail>
 </Col>
 ....
   )
  }
}
```

The above code will show `<h1>SCREEN 1 DATA</h1>` inside the collapsible panel.

Edited:
If you want to reload the page, then modify this section to:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
  <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
  <Route path="/About_Screen" component ={About_Screen} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

`<App>` will only be displayed when you go to `"/"`. When you click the NavLink on that page, the page will be reloaded to `"/About_Screen"`.

Comment: Hi Win Chiu, thanks for your help. If I integrate  {this.props.children} in that way, <h1>SCREEN 1 DATA</h1> the information "only" is added to the existing page. However, I would like to either reload (via NavLink click) the page completely (with the information on About_Screen.js) or replace the information from the start page with the About_Screen information. I do not want to add any information.

Comment: If I do that, I get the following error message: Uncaught Error: A <Router> may have only one child element. I insert the <BrowserRouter>...</BrowserRouter> inside the ReactDOM.render();

Comment: Could you please share the edited version? The BrowserRouter section only.

Comment: Okay. I have it. I had to add a <div> between the <route>'s. Thank you Win Chiu. If I have my final solution I will post it. Hopefully I will not get any more problems :)

Comment: Ehm, sorry.. my mistake. Forgot to wrap the <Route> with <div>. Please check my code again.

Answer (score 0):

should link to another folder? is the file in the same folder?

```
 <NavLink to="/Screen/About_Screen">About</NavLink>
```

Comment: Yes. I want to Link from the existing page to the About_Screen.js page